# what should be obj in the monitor::enter

Tags: c++, .net, c++-cli

I'm still getting familiar with the locking for multithreading.

```
Monitor::Enter(obj);

try
{   
    ///do work
}

finally
{
    Monitor::Exit(obj);
}
```

What and where should `obj` be declared?  I am declaring it in the constructor of the class Locator,

```
Locator()
{ 
    System::Object^ obj = gcnew System::Object();
}
```

and declaring `obj` in private variables of the class

```
private:
    System::Object^ obj;
```

but it's giving me an error after `Monitor::Enter(obj)` saying

```
Value cannot be null.
```

Any tips are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor should be:

```
Locator()
: obj(gcnew System::Object())
{  }
```

What you're doing is creating a new *local* variable which goes out of scope immediately, taking the object it's tracking right with it to an early grave. What you meant to do is initialize the *member* variable instead. In your case, the member variable was left `null` all along, causing the error you observed.

(Since I don't know CLI that well, it might be that you're not allowed to initialize tracked references in the constructor initalizer list. In that case, write it like this:)

```
Locator() { obj = gcnew System::Object(); }
```